# Java atomic methods

Tags: java, atomic

I've been looking into the Java API **java.util.concurrent.atomic**, 
particularly the **AtomicInteger** class.

The method comments say that these methods are atomic.

Take **getAndIncrement()** for example:

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
    for (;;) {
        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))                
        return current;
    }
}
```

which, as it is documented, is  "*Atomically increments by one the current value*."

What exactly is making this method atomic? 
From what i see, it is completely "non-atomic"-- many cycles involved in its execution and, 
during the execution of the statement

```
        int next = current + 1;
```

for instance,  the value of **next** can be set by another thread.

Comment: It's atomic, since any other thread would see it's action as atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The atomicity is handled whithin the `compareAndSet(current, next)` method. The code does the incrementation and sets the new value only if it hasn't been changed yet, and that is done atomically (or it fakes the atomic behaviour). If it's been changed since then, it takes another try. So it might not be atomic, but it acts like it is.

Comment: so it is made atomic operationally, not by managing a lock on it-- as evident from the code or in some other way of blocking other accesses. thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

AtomicInteger uses combination of volatile & CAS (Compare and Swap) for thread-safe implementation of Integer Counter.

Read & write to volatile variables have same memory semantics as that of acquiring and releasing a monitor using synchronized code block. So the visibility of volatile field is guaranteed by the JMM.

AtomicInteger class stores its value field in a volatile variable, thus it is a decorator over the traditional volatile variable, but it provides unique non-blocking mechanism for updating the value after requiring the hardware level support for CAS (compare and set). Under low to moderate thread contention, atomic updates provides higher throughput compared to synchronized blocking increment operation.

Here is the implementation for getAndIncrement() method of AtomicInteger Class.

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
        for (;;) {
            int current = get();
            int next = current + 1;
            if (compareAndSet(current, next))
                return current;
        }
```

}You can see that no lock is acquired to increment the value, rather CAS is used inside infinite loop to update the new value.

Since no locking is required by AtomicInteger, so it can be used to write scalable application where thread contention is low to medium.

Comment: volatile declaration makes the value kept in main memory and not cached or operated on in any other way by compiler for optimization or other purposes for its uses in different methods. volatile fairly makes sure-- dont know the details-- that "that" mem.location is "blocked" while it's in use but doesn't guarantee exclusive access to ensure atomic operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what could happen without loop and CAS, it will be clear what is meant by atomic here.

In the absence of synchronized and compare and set (so no need for loop), your code would be something like

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {

        int current = get();
        int next = current + 1;
        set(next);
        return current;

}
```

In a multithreaded environment, there could be two threads seeing the current value as 0 & trying to update the value to one. Two updates but value incremented by just one. Clearly without sychronization there is no guarantee that this can not happen.

So here is what compareAndSet helps, to see if the value is still zero before incrementing to one. So incaseof compareAndSet we say set the value to 1 only if the current value is zero, else fail. Considering above case of two threads updating the value, at most only one thread will successfully increase the value to 1 and other will fail. Thus honoring the Atomicity ('all or nothing') of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the compareAndSet function implementation all the way to the assembly code you will find that it is translated into an single assembly instruction (cmpxchg for i486, in file linux_i486.s in sun jdk), which is a single instruction that does the exchange of values and hence providing the required atomicity as opposed to locking.